# Cast context of functional interface in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, functional-interface

There's an example of casting a functional interface (as I understand it) in a *cast context*: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html with a code example:

```
 // Cast context
 stream.map((ToIntFunction) e -> e.getSize())...
```

It is described as *"Functional interfaces can provide a target type in multiple contexts, such as assignment context, method invocation, or cast context"*.

I've tried to use `ToIntFunction` with `stream().mapTo()` but could only use it with `stream().mapToInt()` and also not using the cast.

Could someone please provide an example how to use the cast context example?
I've tried this:

```
// dlist is a list of Doubles
dlist.stream().map((ToIntFunction) d -> d.intValue()).forEach(System.out::println)
```

but it works without `(ToIntFunction)`. When do I need the *cast context* anyway?

Also what is the purpose of `mapToInt`. This seems to be equivalent:

```
dlist.stream().mapToInt(d -> d.intValue()).forEach(System.out::println);

dlist.stream().map(d -> d.intValue()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cast context` it means that **Java Compiler** will auto convert `functional interface` to the target `functional interface` type,

As `(ToIntFunction) d -> d.intValue()`, the compiler will auto convert it to: `ToIntFunction toIntFunction = (ToIntFunction<Double>) value -> value.intValue()`

so:

```
dlist.stream().map((ToIntFunction) d -> d.intValue()).forEach(System.out::println)
```

it's equal to:

```
ToIntFunction toIntFunction = (ToIntFunction<Double>) value -> value.intValue();
dlist.stream().mapToInt(toIntFunction).forEach(System.out::println);
```

And for:

```
dlist.stream().mapToInt(Double::intValue).forEach(System.out::println);
dlist.stream().map(Double::intValue).forEach(System.out::println);
```

- `mapToInt`'s `Double::intValue` compiler will convert it to `ToIntFunction<Double>`.
- `map`'s `Double::intValue` compiler will convert it to `Function<Double, Int>`

Comment: Thanks. But `dlist.stream().map((ToIntFunction) d -> d.intValue()).forEach(System.out::println)` does not work. Throws `map(Function<? super Double,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Double> is not applicable for the arguments (ToIntFunction<Double>)` error.

Comment: @implicit_knowledge, as I said, `map` method accept `Function` type parameter, not `ToIntFunction` type, if you want to use `ToIntFunction` type should use `mapToInt` method, if you not, you can just use `Double::intValue` as parameter for `map` method, the compiler will auto infer this.

Comment: Thank you! So this code example from the docs is not executable. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`mapToInt` is used to return a stream of int primitive type, which could have performance benefits over a stream of Integer.
The same is true for the `toIntFunction`, which returns a function of int primitive type.